# removeSelection() influences removeMapLayer() - Message: Layer not registered

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I'm currently writing a plugin in QGIS. Through an action, I want all the selected Features and a specific Layer to be be removed.

```
def deleteLayer(self):

    #remove Selection
    for layer in layerlist:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            layer.removeSelection()

    #deletes Layer
    self.mapRegistry.removeMapLayer(self.layer)
```

Both sections work fine, if run while the other is commented out. Yet, the moment the code is like above it runs as it should... But I get this message from QGIS:

In German: Layer20171201140534272 :: Layer nicht registriert.

English_Translation: Layer20171201140534272 :: Layer is not registered.

Does anyone know what the message means and why it appears?

Edit: Maybe this additional code is important - layerlist does not include self.layer, because it was removed.

```
if self.layer in layerlist:
        layerlist.remove(self.layer)
```

And the message also appears when removeMapLayer() is given the layer.id().

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

I delete the Layer first, then remove the Selection. I still do not know why the message appeared, though.